# DotNetOpenauth Microsoft and Twitter Custom Client

Tags: c#, twitter, dotnetopenauth

I am using DontNetOpenAuth for the first time. After finding the blog [Custom LinkedIn OAuth Provider](http://blog.mrroa.com/post/30454808112/asp-net-custom-linkedin-oauth-provider) I have created my own linkedin custom client and change the following to get extra details

```
const string UserProfileFields = ":(id,first-name,last-name,headline,location:(name),picture-url,email-address,public-profile-url,phone-numbers,date-of-birth)";
protected override AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthenticationCore(AuthorizedTokenResponse response)            
{

                const string profileRequestUrl =
                    "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~" + UserProfileFields;
............
}
```

It works properly. I am trying to use the same concept for MicrosoftClient and twitter client but both are not working. My twitter client is as follows

```
   public class TwitterCustomClient : OAuthClient{
    private static XDocument LoadXDocumentFromStream(Stream stream)
        {
    .......
    }
private static readonly ServiceProviderDescription TwitterServiceDescription =
                new ServiceProviderDescription
                {
                    RequestTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(
                                               "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                                               HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest |
                                               HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest |                                               HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
                    UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(
                                              "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
                                              HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest |
                                              HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest |                                              HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
                    AccessTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(
                                              "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                                              HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest |
                                              HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest |                                              HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest),
                    TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() },
};
public TwitterCustomClient(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret) :
                base("Twitter", TwitterServiceDescription, consumerKey, consumerSecret) { }
protected override AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthenticationCore(AuthorizedTokenResponse response)
            {
                const string profileRequestUrl =                    "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
                string accessToken = response.AccessToken;
                var profileEndpoint =
                    new MessageReceivingEndpoint(profileRequestUrl, HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);
                HttpWebRequest request =
                    WebWorker.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(profileEndpoint, accessToken);
                try
                {
                    using (WebResponse profileResponse = request.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (Stream responseStream = profileResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            XDocument document = LoadXDocumentFromStream(responseStream);
                            string userId = document.Root.Element("id").Value;
                            string userName;
                            Dictionary<string, string> extraData = GetExtraData(accessToken, document, out userName);
                            return new AuthenticationResult(
                                isSuccessful: true,
                                provider: ProviderName,
                                providerUserId: userId,
                                userName: userName,
                                extraData: extraData);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    return new AuthenticationResult(exception);
                }
            }
}
```

But it is getting the following error

> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned
>   an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 524:            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>
> Line 525:            {
>
> Line 526:                OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, ReturnUrl);
>
> Line 527:            }

And also i am not sure how to get extra data (for linkedin it is ?fields=). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Updated: Authorization is working.

I guess the following code is not working

```
const string profileRequestUrl =
                "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/:id";

            string accessToken = response.AccessToken;

            var profileEndpoint =
                new MessageReceivingEndpoint(profileRequestUrl, HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest);
            HttpWebRequest request =
                WebWorker.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(profileEndpoint, accessToken);
            request.Host = "api.twitter.com";
            try
            {
                using (WebResponse profileResponse = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream responseStream = profileResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please reformat your code..

Comment: Twitter isn't liking your creds. Use Fiddler to track what's happening on the wire. Pay particular attention to what is being sent in the authorization header and that it conforms to their documentation. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request for what they need.

Comment: @SonerGönül tried my best to reformat

Comment: @PeterB Thanks for your comment. Yes, something was wrong in the app. I created a new one for twitter. Now it is going to twitter page after  user login it shows the login failure page. I have checked the fiddler it is complaining about "Request is missing the required Host Header". How can i add header on the request? I am confused.

Comment: You can add a host header in Fiddler and/or your.NET client code. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request for what it needs to be (Host: api.twitter.com). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @PeterB for your valuable suggestions. Those has been fixed. Still these two custom clients are not working :(